# Get an interface property value in a generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have this interface

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    IEnumerable<MyParamInfo> Params { get; }
}
```

where
MyParamInfo is

```
public class MyParamInfo 
    {
        public MyParamInfo (string name)
        {
            Name= name;
        }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

also
this class

```
public class MyClass:IMyInterface
{  
   //properties
   ....  
   public IEnumerable<MyParamInfo> Params
   {
      get
        {
         return new List<MyParamInfo> { new MyParamInfo("Param1")};
        }
   }
}
```

and this Form

```
public partial class MyForm<T> : Form where T:Class,IMyInterface
{
  ...
}
```

with this code

```
MyForm<MyClass> frm = new MyForm<MyClass>();
```

How can I access to Params Property of MyClass in frm object?

Comment: Where does `MyClass` fit in here? Is your form supposed to extend `MyClass`?

Comment: Where you use `MyClass` in `MyForm`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you also require that the `T` type parameter of `MyForm` have a parameterless constructor, you can instantiate an instance of `T` and then use the interface property at will.

On the definition of `MyForm`, add the `new()` generic constraint

```
public partial class MyForm<T> : Form where T : Class, IMyInterface, new()
```

Then in some method of `MyForm<T>`, you can use:

```
(new T()).Params;
```

You can read about all the constraints on type parameters in C# [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

It seems like what you really want is interfaces that could specify static methods (so-called static interfaces).  Such a construct does not exist in C#.